# is it possible to do a gated check-in using Team Foundation Service backed by GIT?

Tags: git, build-automation, azure-devops

Using VS2012, Team Foundation **Service** with GIT as my source control provider - I am attempting to create a build definition that uses the "Gated Check-In" option - however - this option is not enabled on the Trigger tab of the build definition creator.

Does anyone know if gated check-ins are available as a build trigger option when using Team Foundation Service and GIT?

Google has not provided the answer - maybe I have not entered the correct terms...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was also looking for answer to the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/26/visual-studio-2013-preview-version-control-tfbuild.aspx

> We've simplified the build process parameters. And of course now you
>   can to build the code you store in a Git team project, and you can
>   generally do everything you can do with code stored in a TFVC team
>   project. **One notable exception: you cannot define a gated check-in
>   build in a Git team project**.

There must be some alternative for it. Now I need to find that out.

Answer (score 0):

Things like this are done in git hooks, which [as of April Microsoft hadn't implemented in their partial re-implmementation of git](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84fea5b9-de95-4157-bb70-5333f86a8eb4/git-commit-hook-stream-available).  That's Microsoft's official Visual Studio Team Foundation Service forum. and about the absence of git hooks its owner has this to say:

> Hi,
>
> Currently we don't have this feature. You can help us prioritize this by submitting suggestions at http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/30925-team-foundation-server.

Comment: thanks for your reply - in the links you provided I could not see where they say that you cannot define a gated check-in using a Git team project - as I did in iSid's response - so I chose his answer.  thank you.

Comment: The reason you can't define a gated check-in build is that they don't do commit hooks, and that thread is a request for commit hooks.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying "why" you can't.  Maybe "why" bit will help other readers get closure on the topic.  I simply wanted to know if it was possible.